# Displaying icon image after form input

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to display some icons in my navbar.

This works okay:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default as-sub-navbar">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="navbar">
            <div class="col-md-3 pull-right">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><img class="as-search-icon" src="~/Content/img/search.png"></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><img class="as-search-icon" src="~/Content/img/circle_delete_dark.png"></li>
                </ul>
                <form class="navbar-form as-sub-navbar-search-form" role="search">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control as-sub-navbar-search-bar" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

[image: screenshot of result]

But when I try to move the "x" image after the search bar, it appears on a new line:

```
<div class="col-md-3 pull-right">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><img class="as-search-icon" src="~/Content/img/search.png"></li>
    </ul>
    <form class="navbar-form as-sub-navbar-search-form" role="search">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control as-sub-navbar-search-bar" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
        </div>
    </form>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><img class="as-search-icon" src="~/Content/img/circle_delete_dark.png"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[image: screenshot of result]

Does anybody have an idea about how to keep them on the same line?

CSS:

```
.as-sub-navbar-search-form{
    margin-top:0px;
}

.as-sub-navbar-search-bar{
    background-color:rgb(233, 234, 235);
    height: 40px;
}

.as-search-icon {
   margin-top: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `float` the search field, so add `float:left;` to the `.navbar-form` for example.

```
.navbar-form {
    float: left;
}
```

[**See my example here.**](http://www.bootply.com/l4DTJuZoj6)